# Como configurar no apache HTTPS para uma página específica e HTTP para as demais?

Tags: apache, ssl, http-status, openssl

Preciso que uma página especifica funcione via HTTPS com um certificado específico.
Como configurar os arquivos httpd.conf, httpd-ssl e httpd-vhosts.conf no apache? tem algum outro arquivo para modificar?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que configurar o domínio em dois Vhosts: um na porta 80 e outro na porta 443. Isso fará com que o site passe a responder tanto em HTTP quanto em HTTPS em qualquer página.

Depois disso é só restringir na sua aplicação quais páginas você quer obrigar que o usuário veja em HTTP ou em HTTPS, verificando o esquema em cada requisição e redirecionando-o conforme for o caso.

A princípio é só incluir os sites nos arquivos `httpd-vhosts.conf` e conferir se as configurações de SSL e certificados estão todos ok. :)

Comment: Rodrigo, tem skype ou e-mail para contato?

Comment: @mcardoso Pode me adicionar no Skype: rodrigo.mammano